# How to switch between fragments in one same tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

My little app has the following basic structure (2 tabs in tabhost):

Main (extends FragmentActivity)
HomeFragment (extends Fragment)
ConfigFragment (extends Fragment)

Sometimes (when user click in menu) i need show other fragment (GraphicFragment) instead HomeFragment. Will be that when I'm in GraphicFragment and use the back button (or menu item Home), the tab again show the fragment HomeFragment.

How to do this?

main.xml (the layout):

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Main.java:

public class Main extends FragmentActivity{

```
private TabHost mTabHost;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, Main.TabInfo>();
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private Config config;

private class TabInfo {

    private String tag;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Class<?> clss;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Bundle args;

    TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.clss = clazz;
        this.args = args;
    }

}

private class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }

}   

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    initializeTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }

    intializeViewPager();

    config = Config.GetInstance();
    config.setContext(getApplicationContext());     
}

private void initializeTabHost(Bundle args){
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    TabInfo tabInfo = null;

    Main.addTab(
        this,
        mTabHost,
        mTabHost.newTabSpec("Home").setIndicator("Home"),
        (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Home", HomeFragment.class, args)));
    mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    Main.addTab(
        this,
        mTabHost,
        mTabHost.newTabSpec("Config").setIndicator("Config"),
        (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Config", ConfigFragment.class, args)));
    mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);        

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(tabChangeListener);
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
    outState.putString("tab", "Home");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void intializeViewPager() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, HomeFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ConfigFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, GraphicFragment.class.getName()));

    mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
}

private static void addTab(Main activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

private final TabHost.OnTabChangeListener tabChangeListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener(){

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int pos = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }
};  

private final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    }
};
```

}

Fragments:

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Config config = Config.GetInstance();

private View view;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Context context;    

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    if(container == null){
        return null;
    }

    view = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_graphic, container, false);
    context = view.getContext();

    return view;

}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tab_graphic, menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_home:
            loadGraphicFragment();
    }

    return false;
}

public void loadGraphicFragment(){

    Fragment fragment = new GraphicFragment();

    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, fragment);
    transaction.commit();       
}
```

}

error in time execution:

```
11-28 18:09:13.673: E/AndroidRuntime(468): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:801)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1010)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:523)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:495)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:476)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at br.com.censanet.connectionmonitor.Main$1.onTabChanged(Main.java:125)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.widget.TabHost.invokeOnTabChangeListener(TabHost.java:353)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:338)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:379)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:852)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-28 18:09:13.695: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Please, help-me!
(sorry for english!)

Comment: Have you solved this issue? i have the same problem please help me. Please tell me if you have any alternate to solve this problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can download sample code from here very useful for tab type projects.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

**Update** 
here you can find more about fragments.

[change fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group)

Comment: Ok I got it :) will talk to you tomorrow.