# Using SectionsPagerAdapter android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a sectionsPagerAdapter that is used as the adapter for a ViewPager.

```
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

I have 3 fragments and  I want to switch between 2 fragments when  a button is clicked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm gonna guess that your SectionsPagerAdapter was automatically generated when you created a new activity using ADT and specified a navigation type with tabs.  If that's the case, then your SectionsPagerAdapter is extending FragmentPagerAdapter, [whose documentation is located here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html).

If you really want to use a ViewPager for what you're talking about, check out that link to the Android developer reference.  It sounds, though, like you want to do something more akin to [what's discussed in this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group).  Maybe you could elaborate a bit on what you're looking to accomplish?

Comment: I have been through the links and I have done my research and got the output. Thanks..:)