# Nesting two layoutinflators , extending fragmentpageadapter and a baseadapter

Tags: android

i want to implement tabs with each tab populating a listview with data. So basically i want an inflator for a tab and for each inflator another way to inflate the records.
Here is a part of my code.

MainActivity -

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;   
    static ListView lv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songs_list);
    ArrayList<NewsItem> image_details = getListData();
    lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getBaseContext(), image_details));

}
```

I guess something is wrong with the getBaseContext here.

Here is my songs fragment

```
        public static class Songs_Fragment extends Fragment {

    public Songs_Fragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Finally here is part of the customadapter

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_movies, parent, false );
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reporter);
        holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    NewsItem newsItem = (NewsItem) listData.get(position);

    holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getHeadline());
    holder.reporterNameView.setText("By, " + newsItem.getReporterName());
    holder.reportedDateView.setText(newsItem.getDate());

    if (holder.imageView != null) {
        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

The application crashes - what am i doing wrong? am i trying to inflate an element which is not yet inflated itself - i have wasted so much time on this.

Log -

```
    03-16 07:55:05.102: W/dalvikvm(4272): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.justanotherblog.swipeview/net.justanotherblog.swipeview.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634) 
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at net.justanotherblog.swipeview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    03-16 07:55:05.102: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     ... 11 more
```

Layout of songs_fragment.xml -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/songs_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_flatcolor" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the logcat output of your crash?

Comment: I'm guessing that this question probably refers to your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536405/using-sectionspageradapter-android

Comment: @daentech - i put on the log file - it shows a null pointer exception.

Comment: @AndyFaizan - Not really, i have a working fragmentpageadapter implementing the tabs and a working listview populator. Now i want to integrate the listview within one of the tabs. The listview element is contained inside one of the fragments of the tab. The problem is that when i try to inflate the listview in the beginning it causes an error - which i suspect is because the tab view is yet to be inflated itself - it has no parent to attach to.. i will really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Yes I guess you're right. Could you point out which one is line 49 in your Activity class? That's where the NPE is occurring

Comment: @AndyFaizan it is                                                      lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, image_details));

Comment: Without it the program doesn't crash - but obviously the listview is not populated :/

Comment: Well could you post your getListData() method and your layout xml?

Comment: @AndyFaizan - okay i will.. thanks for helping... An idea i had was maybe to move the listview.setAdapter after the fragment is inflated, but it turns out that i cannot pass the context as it is a a non-static method and listview is static

Comment: Why is the listview static?

Comment: I made it static because if i didn't the error which appeared when i shifted the setAdapter after the tabinflaor was - "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field lv1". After i made it static the error is "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getBaseContext() from the type ContextWrapper"

Comment: wait - i will put the project code on git

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/abhisaarsharma/test/src     the swipeview zip is the one -

Comment: This is solved ... i posted another question.. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440442/null-pointer-exception-while-inflating-listview/22440450?noredirect=1#22440450