# I cannot add any function for my fragment's java files

Tags: java, android-fragments

***UPDATES***

I added more java files just in case you find them helpful. I figured that I may need to write codes to connect between `MainActivity.java` and my `fragments`, but the codes I followed from several YouTube videos do not work. I would be greatly appreciated if you can write me a line of code to connect the fragment.

***END OF UPDATES***

Whenever I try to add functions in my fragment file, it does not work. I think I may miss some codes in `MainActivity.java`, but I have no idea what to add to make my fragment's java files work.

Here is my fragment's `java` file (I did not touch anything but added a simple function to show a check mark when a button is clicked):

```
package com.example.dailybible3;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link FragmentBible#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentBible extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public FragmentBible() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment fragment_bible.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentBible newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentBible fragment = new FragmentBible();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bible, container, false);
        Button btn_complete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.complete_button);
        btn_complete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ImageView check_mark = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.check_mark);
                int visibility = check_mark.getVisibility();
                if(visibility == View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    check_mark.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    check_mark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Just in case, here is my `xml` file as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentBible"
    android:theme="@style/FontStyle">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_background_round" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_string"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/title_image"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title_string"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title_string"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/title_string"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_bible_english" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:background="@drawable/light_background_round_english" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/niv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/centerline"
            android:text="NIV"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/kjv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/centerline"
            android:text="KJV"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/centerline"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_background"
            android:elevation="10dp"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/complete_button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtitle1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Leviticus 2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtitle_text1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle1"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/subtitle1"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:text="1) When anyone brings a grain offering to the Lord, their offering is to be of the finest flour. They are to pour olive oil on it, put incense on it 2) and take it to Aaron’s sons the priests. The priest shall take a handful of the flour and oil, together with all the incense, and burn this as a memorial portion on the altar, a food offering, an aroma pleasing to the Lord."
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtitle2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle_text1"
                    android:text="Leviticus 2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtitle_text2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle2"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/subtitle2"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:text="1) When anyone brings a grain offering to the Lord, their offering is to be of the finest flour. They are to pour olive oil on it, put incense on it 2) and take it to Aaron’s sons the priests. The priest shall take a handful of the flour and oil, together with all the incense, and burn this as a memorial portion on the altar, a food offering, an aroma pleasing to the Lord."
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtitle3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle_text2"
                    android:text="Leviticus 2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtitle_text3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle3"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/subtitle3"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:text="1) When anyone brings a grain offering to the Lord, their offering is to be of the finest flour. They are to pour olive oil on it, put incense on it 2) and take it to Aaron’s sons the priests. The priest shall take a handful of the flour and oil, together with all the incense, and burn this as a memorial portion on the altar, a food offering, an aroma pleasing to the Lord."
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/complete_button_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60sp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/light_background_round_english" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/check_mark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/complete_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/complete_button"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/complete_button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/complete_button"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_english"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/complete_button_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Complete"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/complete_button_background"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/complete_button_background"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/complete_button_background"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/complete_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/complete_button_background"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/complete_button_background"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/complete_button_background"
            android:layout_marginTop="7sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/complete_button_text"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button_round" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.dailybible3;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.dailybible3.ui.main.SectionsPagerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);


        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
}
```

Also, here is the adapter:

```
package com.example.dailybible3.ui.main;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.example.dailybible3.R;

/**
 * A [FragmentPagerAdapter] that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    @StringRes
    private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2, R.string.tab_text_3, R.string.tab_text_4, R.string.tab_text_5};
    private final Context mContext;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 5 total pages.
        return 5;
    }
}
```

And here is `PlaceHolderFragment.java`:

```
package com.example.dailybible3.ui.main;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.dailybible3.R;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    private PageViewModel pageViewModel;

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int index) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, index);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel.class);
        int index = 1;
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            index = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        }
        pageViewModel.setIndex(index);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = null;

        switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
        {
            case 1:
                root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bible, container, false);
                break;
            case 3:
                root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);
                break;
            case 4:
                root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);
                break;
            case 5:
                root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_records, container, false);
                break;
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

And here is the `PageViewModel.java` (which I am not quite sure why it is needed):

```
package com.example.dailybible3.ui.main;

import androidx.arch.core.util.Function;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class PageViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Integer> mIndex = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private LiveData<String> mText = Transformations.map(mIndex, new Function<Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Integer input) {
            return "Hello world from section: " + input;
        }
    });

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        mIndex.setValue(index);
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `MainActivity` makes no reference to `FragmentBible`; how are these things connected?

Comment: @codebod Thank you for your writing! I'm not very used to code fragments, and may I ask you to help me write the code to connect these two files? I watched some YouTube videos and found some codes like `sectionsPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new Fragment(), "frag1")`, but they do not work for mine.

Comment: See if this helps at all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19100199/13373270.

Comment: That was helpful, and I solved the issue. Thank you.