# missing parameter when creating a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

In my first attempt to work with `Fragments`, the method `replace` gives this error `The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, LM_Fragment)` I supplied the `id` of the first `fragment` which is `lm_fragment` as the first parameter for `.replace` method. is that correct? if not what parameter should I supply `.replace` method with?

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

      if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
         LM_Fragment lm_fragment = new LM_Fragment();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.lm_fragment, lm_fragment);
      }else{
         PM_Fragment pm_fragment = new PM_Fragment();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.pm_fragment, pm_fragment);
      }
      fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }
```

MainActivity xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

     <fragment
        android:name="com.example.fragments"
        android:id="@+id/lm_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.fragments"
        android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Does your LM_Fragment class inhert from android's Fragment class?

Comment: yes "public class LM_Fragment extends Fragment"

Comment: You need to pass `containerViewId` as First argument of your `.replace(....)`

Comment: Take a look on this [http://notionink.wikidot.com/rajeshbabu](http://notionink.wikidot.com/rajeshbabu) And [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group)

Comment: is `containerViewId ` the same as `<frgment` id?

Answer (score 0):

Your LM_Fragment should be inheriting the Fragment class. Also in `replace(int, fragment)` you should pass container id. Container is the view which will hold the fragment, its not the fragment id.