# getArgument is NULL, why?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, bundle

I am trying to pass values through a `Bundle`using `setArguments()` from an activity to another class extends `Fragment` when I press one of the listed items in a `ListView`.

As shown below, I used a `Log.i` statement to know if the `Bundle` received is `null` or not. Unfortunately, it is always `null` and consequently, no data shows on the designated `TextView` of the class that extends `Fragment`. What I am missing or what is wrong with the code.

**`FragmentClass`:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentclasslayout, null);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getArgument is not null");
        int value = getArguments().getInt("pos");           
        TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvID);
        tv.setTextSize(value);
        tv.setText("size = "+value*10);
    }else {
        Log.i(TAG, "getArgument is null");
    }
}
```

**`MainClass_implements_onItemSelectedListener`:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);

    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.listviewlayout, R.id.tv, string);
    mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Fragment f = new FragmentClass();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putInt("pos", (position+1));
    FragmentClass fc = new FragmentClass().newInstance(bundle);
    //f.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentTransaction t =
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            t.replace(R.id.fragment00ID, f);
            t.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            t.addToBackStack(null);
            t.commit();
}
```

**`mainActivity_layout`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.fragmentwithlistview.FragmentClass"
    android:id="@+id/fragment00ID"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4" />
```

**`FragmentClass_layout`:**

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvID"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: how are you setting arguments

Comment: @IllegalArgument please have alook at the method `onitemselected' it is `bundle.putInt("pos", (position+1));` is that what you mean?

Comment: R.id.fragment00ID refers to your activity layout you want to replace right??

Comment: yes, i will post the layout as well shortly

Comment: anything to do with addToBackStack(null)?

Comment: @kevin no, i just used `addToBackStack(null)` so later when the app. works, i know how `addToBackStack(null)` works

Comment: @IllegalArgument i posted the entire layoout

Comment: The first answer of this shall help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group

Comment: @kevin i think they mainly talking about replacing a fragment with another programmatically, which  already did

Comment: @Amr The point is you cannot replace a fragment hard coded in xml. The `FragmentTransaction.replace` code in your `onItemSelected` failed silently (I assume), the fragment is still the one in your xml, which does not contain any arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use a static method for instantiating:

```
public class FragmentClass extends Fragment {

  public static FragmentClass newInstance(Bundle b) {
    FragmentClass fragment = new FragmentClass();
    fragment.setArguments(b);

    return fragment;
  }

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentclasslayout, null);

      if (getArguments() != null) {
          Log.i(TAG, "getArgument is not null");
          int value = getArguments().getInt("pos");           
          TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvID);
          tv.setTextSize(value);
          tv.setText("size = "+value*10);
      } else {
          Log.i(TAG, "getArgument is null");
      }

      return view;
  }
}
```

Then simply call that method and pass the arguments-bundle as a parameter:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("pos", (position+1));
FragmentClass f = FragmentClass.newInstance(bundle);
```

Also, don't use `onActivityCreated` for fetching the arguments in your FragmentClass, use `onCreateView` or if required `onStart` or `onResume`. Have a look at fragment-lifecycles: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: I triied your suggestion but still no data appears?

Comment: I tried it, the same thing again, no data output, the fragment area is aemptyt

Comment: AFAIK, in `onCreateView` one can't initialise the view's using `getview.finditembyid()` because the view has not fully initialised yet. but inside it we can initialise objects and instantiate them. am I right?

Comment: Why are you instantiating your fragment outside of `onItemSelected`? I guess that's where your problem is then, look at kevin's comment. In `onCreateView` you inflate your view and use `findViewById` on that view.

Comment: I just noticed in your edit: not `new FragmentClass().newInstance`, just `FragmentClass.newInstance`. Other than that it's hard to give more advice, pay attention to how you use the `FragmentManager` as well as to the Fragment lifecycles.

Comment: Very wrong again, please pay attention! I edited my answer again. You do NOT use the constructor anymore if you use `newInstance`.

Comment: kindly please bear with me, i cant figure out where my mistake is, is it in the body of onCreateView or in onitemselected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54629/discussion-between-blacklight-and-amr).

Answer (score 0):

You can use in passing Activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("model", strDeckNumber);

                    final FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    Frag1 newFragment = new Frag1();
                    newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    t.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                    t.addToBackStack(TAG);
                    t.commit();
```

Receiving Fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            strSeriesNumber = getArguments().getString("model");
}
```