# Display different class/xml depending on condition in Tab Bar Fragments for Android

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, tabs

I have a bit of a weird scenario. I have two different xml views that I will display to the user depending on a specific condition. I am using a tab bar with fragments as the tabs. Is it possible to, lets say, display view one, then click a button on that view, and then that entire view will change to view two while still on the same tab bar and the tab bars still on the bottom. Maybe some sort of animation or something to show a transition would occur but that would not be important just yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for fragment http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html this should help you. What you have to do is display a fragment (wich is a portion of the activity) that you can inflate from xml and then replace that fragment like in that post [Replacing a fragment with another fragment inside activity group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group)