# How to remove fragment from stack programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my application, from MainActivity I go to Fragment1 and from Fragment1 I replace Fragment1 with Fragment2. Now I want to remove Fragment1 from stack. How I do this?

Comment: if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            // handling fragment backbutton navigation
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing a fragment with another fragment inside activity group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group)

Comment: If ur replacing Frament1 with fragment2 there is not change to backstack the fragment1. Replace Fragment = Add New fragment +Remove the old Fragment

Comment: if you are replacing a fragment than fragment1 is removed by itself. but if you add fragment than it will add it to stack.

Answer (score 1):

When you are added the fragment,just add the **TAG** for that fragment.
With the use of that **TAG** you can easily remove your old fragment.
Eg.

```
FragmentManager  fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.replace(R.id.container,new MyFragment(),"TAG_FRAGMENT1").commit();
```

To remove old fragment use below code,

```
Fragment oldFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("TAG_FRAGMENT1");
fm.beginTransaction().remove(oldFragment).commit();
```

After removing old fragment you can able to add new fragment.