# How to replace the new fragment to old fragment inside frame layout without viewpager in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

1. I'm trying below code to replace the new fragment, but it's not
   Replaced.

   android.app.Fragment Manager fragmentManager = ((Activity) context).
   getFragmentManager(); android.app.FragmentTransaction
   fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_container,
   menuItemDetailsFragment); fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                       fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: Do you mean navigating From one fragment to another ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group check this and see if it answers your problem

Comment: Yes sir, when user click on the old fragment button, then opens a new fragment.Finally means replace the new fragment. I did above code but the fragments are overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to use the `replace` function
Just replace this line of code

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_container, menuItemDetailsFragment);
```

with this

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, menuItemDetailsFragment);
```