# Update data from spinner activity in fragment and refresh

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have main activity like this:

[MainActivity and ExampleFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehCj8.png)

I need to update my fragment when some one change something in spinner. I know i can use interfaces, and im using it in my application but in this case i cant do that. I searched some many topics in stackoverflow and there i found only this:

```
                        if (myFragment.getArguments() != null) {
                            myFragment.getArguments().putParcelable(Constants.USER,user);
                            myFragment.getArguments().putParcelable(Constants.PATIENT,pickedPatient);
                        }
```

I was trying detach and then attach my fragment to refresh, but data in bundle is not updated, and my fragment is just empty. I checked my logs and old data is still available.

Is there any solution for that problem? Or can I access my toolbar with spinner in my fragments and then update data in whole activity?

Some example with my another fragment here:

[AnotherFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGgG6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new Fragment instance for the myFragment like

```
myFragment = new MyFragment();
```

And use **.replace** method to change the fragment.

Comment: But i have to know which fragment i have to use. How create new instance when i have old fragment from:

Fragment myFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);

Comment: You can create different fragments in java. So with that way you will know which fragment you are using and you can replace it by using replace method like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18940937/4376058

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, i just did sth like that:

https://pastebin.com/FUyVG5rm