# Replace a full screen fragment with another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment (fragment_1) which gets displayed when the main activity starts and displays a full screen layout (layout_1). Now i have added a button, clicking on which will start a new fragment (fragment_2)and replace the entire layout (layout_1) with my new layout (layout_2).

My first fragment (fragment_1) has a ScrollView as my root view.

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#fff"
android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
android:id="@+id/scroll_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
....

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Now i want to start a new fragment (fragment_2) on a button click and display another layout (layout_2) but i don't know how to do that.
My main activity had a frame layout like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/root_container">
```

And i used to set this as my default layout using

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

After this i start my first fragment and display the layout_1.

Now from fragment_1 i want to start fragment_2 and display the layout_2. I have read online articles and documentation where i can't find and solution regarding this. Pleas Note :" I don't want to  simply replace a part of my layout_1 and replace it  with my layout_2 rather i want my layout_1 totally gets replaced with layout_2 on a button click"

Answer (score 0):

Replacing fragments seems like a job for the fragment manager. 
This answer might help you [Replacing a fragment with another fragment inside activity group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group)