# How to replace one fragment with another with two buttons

Tags: java, android

[image]

I am opening the application and it crashed

Comment: Show your activity_main.xml file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing a fragment with another fragment inside activity group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group)

Comment: show java class and xml aslo show logcat error

Comment: please, show us your logcat output. we need to see your error.

Answer (score 0):

You can be write **FragmentTransaction** inside the *onClick* of button.
 Follow below code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button frag1, frag2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frag1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.frag1btn);
        frag2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.frag2btn);
        frag1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment1());
                trans.commit();
            }
        });
        frag2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment2());
                trans.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```