# How to load a new activity inside a fragment without losing the bottom navbar

Tags: java, android

As the title says when on the "Home Fragment" when i click on an image tile I want the new activity to load but I would like to keep the navbar visible. Currently with the code below the activity starts but the navbar disappears. I would like help to write code so the activity starts but the navbar stays.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private ImageView imageCbt;
private ImageView imageDistorted;

@Nullable
@Override
public android.view.View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // get the button view
    imageCbt = getView().findViewById(R.id.whatIsCbt);
    imageDistorted = getView().findViewById(R.id.distortedThinking);

    // set a onclick listener for when the button gets clicked
    imageCbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // Start new list activity
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    IntroActivity2.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });

    imageDistorted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // Start new list activity
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    TwelveTypesDistortedThinkingActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);



        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Maybe you don't need to start a new activity but to replace the current fragment to another one. Then the navbar won't change and the content you want will be visible.

Comment: I'm a complete beginner, can you show me the code on how to do this?

Comment: Kindly refer fragments : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments for sample code and better understanding

Answer (score 0):

To change the current fragment, you can replace the code inside your click listeners to this one ([Replacing a fragment with another fragment inside activity group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group)):

```
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Then you need to convert your activities to Fragment (maybe some refactoring will be necessary) and to change the current fragment in the onClickListener methods.

PS: When you use a navbar, fragments are a best practice in application architecture.

Comment: Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

//               Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
//              and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

//              Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();

Comment: The FragmentTransaction and getSupportFragmentManager() displays in red with an error saying 'unable to resolve'

Comment: If you're inside a Fragment you have access to the activity after the onActivityCreated was called by using getActivity(). Then getActivity().getFragmentManager() will work. For the FragmentTransaction, maybe you're missing a library or an import.

Comment: Thank you for your help this was very helpful